# Freeing array of c-strings

Tags: c++, c-strings

Here I have an array of dynamically-allocated c-strings.

- What is the proper way to free such an array?
- It is necessary to individually free each element of `A`, as code below?

Thank you.

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    const char** A = new const char*[3];
    A[0] = (const char*)memcpy(new char[5], "str0", 5);
    A[1] = (const char*)memcpy(new char[5], "str1", 5);
    A[2] = (const char*)memcpy(new char[5], "str2", 5);

    // Is this the proper way to free everything?
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        delete[] A[i];
    delete[] A;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector<std::string>` and leave the memory management to the standard library?

Comment: Just use a `vector<string>`.

Comment: `#include <string>` -- Yet you failed to use `std::string`.  This is the header that defines `std::string`, `std::wstring`, etc.  I don't know what else you expected when you included this header.

Comment: @Nathan I think that'd be so much cleaner too! Unfortunately, my problem is that it's from a huge codebase that I don't have much control over. The original developers mention **c-strings are faster than library strings** (I researched about this, and it seems that the performance gain is almost negligible.)

Comment: @Paul Thanks! I was meant to say `<string.h>`, for `memcpy`. Corrected.

Comment: `c-strings are faster than library strings` -- Nothing stopped them from writing a simple C++ class that handles strings.  If they were competent, it shouldn't have taken more than an hour.

Comment: @SamShen Yeah there should almost be no difference between `std::string` and doing it yourself.  When you get the added benefits of all the built in functions, memory safety and ease of use it is worth using `std::string`.  About the only time not to is if you know you have/need a fixed sized buffer.

Comment: Instead they make you write a C-style cast of a `memcpy` to a pointer allocated by `new`. My eyes hurt :'-(

Comment: @anatolyg The string literals do define 5 characters each, don't forget about the `\0`.

Comment: Yeah, I counted the bytes wrong. If you never change the length of your strings, you should be OK.

Comment: @TheVee I guess the part with `memcpy` and casting is not code that OP really uses; it could just be replaced with `...`. It's there to make it a [mcve] - (my guess).

Comment: Everything is, memory-wise, fine in your example. You should always use valgrind, or equivalent, to check for errors with respect to memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Everything is OK as long as every `new ...[]` is matched with a `delete[] ...`.